# Как отправлять форму Contact Form 7 на разные email адреса?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Как в зависимости от выбора пункта меню отправлять письмо на тот или иной ел адрес?

Я нашла, как это решить, но появилась новая проблема. При выборе одного пункта меню письмо уходит только на один ящик, а при выборе второго надо, чтобы уходило на 2 ящика сразу.

Comment: Приложите код, как вы решили проблему

Comment: [select* city include_blank "город1|email1@bk.ru" "gorod2|email2@gmail.com"]

Comment: Нет, это плохое решение

Comment: а как правильно??

Comment: Добавил ответ, задавайте вопросы, если они будут

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальный фильтр `wpcf7_mail_components` где вы можете изменить данные письма:

```
function my_wpcf7_main_components( $components ) {

    if ( 398 !== absint( $_POST['_wpcf7'] ) ) { // ID формы
        return $components;
    }
    if ( 500 !== absint( $_POST['_wpcf7_container_post'] ) ) { // ID поста
        return $components;
    }

    $components['recipient'] = 'aa@aaa.aaa,bb@bbb.bb'; // Меняете почты на нужные вам

    return $components;
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'my_wpcf7_main_components' );
```

Comment: А куда это вставить нужно?

Comment: В functions.php

Answer (score 0):

> Как в зависимости от выбора пункта меню отправлять письмо на тот или иной ел адрес?

Для этого нужно вставить в форму выпадающий список вида

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                    "Sales|sales@example.com"
                    "Support|support@example.com"]
```

Подробней см в документации: https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: А причем тут меню?) Выпадающий список !== меню

Comment: @WPPunk Поскольку ни меню ВП, ни вообще какое-либо другое "меню"  вообще не имеет отношения к CF7, то я почти уверен, что "пункт меню" у ТС - это именно "пункт select" (option в см).